Let's get critical: Oct 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love LEGO® Answers, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

What are the inspirational resources for building with Duplo?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

EV3 additional build instructions - PDF download or print possible?
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

How can you estimate the value of a LEGO collection?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

How to repair cracked/peeling decals?
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

Are those bowls genuine LEGO pieces?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

How long does official Lego monorail track last?
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

How to use Power Functions with Mindstorms EV3?
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

Is it possible to shrink down a wheel?
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

Part assortments for creative building
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

Is there a fix for an NXT reporting "File error!" when running an EV3 program?
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)


